# can't stop recording using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm showing an wave to visualize the microphone input. I'm doing it like in the code below.

```
function micWaveForm (allowScan) {
"use strict";
var paths = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
var visualizer = document.getElementById('visualizer');
var mask = visualizer.getElementById('mask');
var path;
var report = 0;

var soundAllowed = function (stream) {
    //Audio stops listening in FF without // window.persistAudioStream = stream;
    //https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=965483
    //https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/984179
    window.persistAudioStream = stream;
    var audioContent = new AudioContext();
    var audioStream = audioContent.createMediaStreamSource( stream );
    var analyser = audioContent.createAnalyser();
    audioStream.connect(analyser);
    analyser.fftSize = 1024;

    var frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    visualizer.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 255 255');

    //Through the frequencyArray has a length longer than 255, there seems to be no
    //significant data after this point. Not worth visualizing.
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 255; i++) {
        path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
        path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', '0');
        mask.appendChild(path);
    }
    var doDraw = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(doDraw);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyArray);
        var adjustedLength;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < 255; i++) {
            adjustedLength = Math.floor(frequencyArray[i]) - (Math.floor(frequencyArray[i]) % 5);
            paths[i].setAttribute('d', 'M '+ (i) +',255 l 0,-' + adjustedLength);
        }
    }
    doDraw();

}

var soundNotAllowed = function (error) {
    console.log(error);
}


if (allowScan) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, soundAllowed, soundNotAllowed);
} else {
    //Stop the recording
}
};
```

The allowScan variable is a bool to start and stop the recording. It's starting when I press a button with the code `navigator.getUserMedia();`, then I tried to stop it but nothings work. Is there a way to disable the microphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `soundAllowed(stream)` function, you can stop the recording by executing `stream.getTracks()[0].stop()` assuming that you only have that media track active.

Comment: If I add that line of code the wave to visualize my recordings stops so thanks for that but the red icon at the top keep displaying. Any idea to get rid of this.

Comment: Where exactly are you making the `stop()` function call? Seems to work fine in a mock object, recording stops and the circular red icon disappears.

Comment: @RSel To be absolute sure, you may loop through the `getTracks()` method and call `stop()` in each one. Either way, according to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility), the feature may be dropped and should be replaced with [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: I copied my code to a jsfiddle project so you can see my code fully. https://jsfiddle.net/r4absotp/37/ . I changed everything you said but it still doesn't stop.